# Read strings and integers from the same txt file in C

Tags: c

I am quite new to programming. I have written a program in C which reads 2 string variables and 1 integer variable in each line of a txt file. I have used `strtok` and `strdup` to separate the first and second string variables of each line but I don't know how to do this with the third variable in order to make the program see it as an integer...

`txt` file is like :

```
jb12, No1, 13  
jto185, No2, 10  
500grl, No3, 24    
effer, No2, 8  
1801, No1, 6  
120B, No3, 18  
tripl, No4, 2  
etb460, No5, 5
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define STRING_SIZE 10
#define LINESIZE 128
#define SIZE 8

struct mold_data {

char mold_type[STRING_SIZE];  
char box_type[STRING_SIZE];  
int box_capacity;   
};

struct mold_data array[SIZE];

 int main (){

 int nob;
 float quantity;
 float num_of_boxes;
 char mold_inserted[STRING_SIZE]; 

 FILE *myfile = fopen ("Mold_data_for_all_clients.txt", "r" );
 int i=0;
 int j=0;
 int k=0;
 int l=0;
 char *result[4][3];
 char line[LINESIZE];
 char *value;

 for(i=0; i<=3; i++){
    for(j=0;j<=2;j++){
        result[i][j] = NULL;
    }
}
i=0;

printf("Type mold type");
scanf("%s",mold_inserted);  
printf("Type ordered quantity");  
scanf("%f",&quantity);    

// loop through each entry in "Mold_data_for_all_clients" file //

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), myfile)){  

    //load mold name
    value = strtok(line, ", ");
    result[i][0] = strdup(value);
    array[i].mold_type==result[i][0];

    //load box type
    value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    result[i][1] = strdup(value);
    array[i].box_type==result[i][1];


    // load box capacity
    value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    result[i][2] = strdup(value);
    array[i].box_capacity==result[i][2];


if (strcmp(mold_inserted,result[i][0])==0)

    {
    num_of_boxes=quantity/array[i].box_capacity;
    nob=ceil(num_of_boxes);

    printf("\n %d   " "%s",nob,result[i][1]);  }
    break;

    //go to next line
    i++;
}   


fclose(myfile);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you seem to have is a [*Comma-Separated Values* (or *CSV*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. You already have the last value, it's stored as a string in `value` after the last `strtok` call. You only need to [convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) it to an integer.

Comment: By the way, your program will not compile: You can not assign to an array, only copy to it. And you will have memory leaks. And there's no need for the array `result`. And you seem to mistake comparison for equality (using `==`) with assignment (using `=`). And you unconditionally break out of the loop the first iteration. Actually, you don't even seem to need the `array` array either, or the structure itself.

Comment: Thank you all! I corrected the mistakes you mentioned and also I kept only the struct array ( instead of result array). Now it seems to be working fine! Really helpful advice!

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to your problem. The first is to use `atoi()` to convert a string to an integer, like so:

```
array[i].box_capacity = atoi(value);
```

The other solution is to use `sscanf()` to parse your lines:

```
sscanf(line, "%10[^,]s, %10[^,]s, %d", array[i].mold_type, array[i].box_type, &array[i].box_capacity);
```

Here, `%10[^,]s` means a string of any character excluding commas, with a maximum length of 10 characters. Note: you should check the return value of `sscanf()` to ensure you read all the elements. Also, it might be possible to avoid using `fgets()` by using `fscanf(myfile, ...)` instead.